# How to find the cumulative size of a directory

Tags: windows, dir

Is there a switch for the `dir` command which lists the size of a directory as well?

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) page says:

> Dir also displays the total number of files and directories listed, their cumulative size, and the free space (in bytes) remaining on the disk.

But it doesn't to specify how! Any help is appreciated.

I am not looking for batch scripts but just for one line command.

Answer (score 6):

Try `dir /s /a directory-name`.  You'll see a total byte count in the 2nd to last line.  The `/a` flag tells it to include any system or hidden files in the count.

Comment: Won't work, args are incorrect.

Comment: Works for me on both Win7 x64 and WinXP.  I don't know why you're having trouble.

Comment: It actually works for you with a space after the **/a**? Weird. Also, /as /ah will *only* include system and hidden files, not all files. /a by itself will include everything.

Comment: You bet.  On both machines.  Mind you, I think `dir` is totally clunky and don't use it myself but, yeah, it worked when I tried it (and retried it after you raised an objection.)  Personally, I would do it more straightforwardly with my own `ls` command as `ls -lw! directory` where `-l` means long listing, `-w` means walk subdirs to calculate sizes and `-!` means list just the directory, not its contents, producing a single line of output with the result.  But I understood the OP as asking how to do with only what comes from Microsoft and this seemed to do it

Comment: Wow, ok. Note I'm pursuing this only because now I've *very* interested in this seemingly aberrant behaviour! In all the years I've used dir, it's either been `dir /a:s /a:h` or `dir /as /ah` (as MS says in the Help/docs, "Using a colon (:) is optional. Use any combination of these values, and **do not separate the values with spaces**"). `dir /a s /a h` makes no sense to me, since I interpret it as "display **all files** in the dir **s** and the dir **h** respectively" (just tested it on Win7 x64). So how is it working for you with the spaces? Also, how is /as /ah returning *all* files/dirs?

Comment: P.S. Just tested on English XP 32-bit and Win7 32-bit too, works the same way! (That is, **/a s /a h** implies dirs named **s** and **h**), and /as /ah does not show all files, only /a by itself does). Curiouser and curiouser! Are you sure you did not test in your own shell? :)

Comment: `dir /s /as /ah directory` doesn't work for me, either.  Same with colons.  As for making sense of this, I'm the author of Hamilton C shell, a UNIX shell alternative to `cmd.exe`, so I'm pretty much the LAST person you should to look to for an explanation or defense of why `cmd.exe` works the way it does.  I have no idea why people put up with what I regard as a complete POS. :)

Comment: Heh (and yeah, by "your shell" I was referring to your software). Still, `dir /s /as /ah directory` works fine on all 3 systems here and displays hidden and system files/dirs in the specified dir and all its sub-dirs. I know I am probably not gonna rest easy till I figure this out...

Comment: What I meant by "doesn't work" is that I only get just hidden and system, not all files without the spaces.  I appreciate it's a reasonable question, but no, I typed it directly into a `cmd.exe` prompt on both machines (and tried it again!) and it really did work.  I long ago gave up trying to explain the quirks in the `cmd.exe` parser.  FWIW, I think your idea, using only `/a` is probably better, btw.  I just didn't happen to try that before answering.

Comment: I am getting all files with `/a s /a h` in the dirs `s and h` only if I have such dirs obviously. If I don't have the 2 dirs I get "File Not Found" as expected. That's it, I'm probably gonna ask others here to explain this, because I can't.

Comment: I'm getting the same result as @Karan... Specifically, I'm getting `File Not Found`.

Comment: Are you typing `dir /s /a h /a s directory-name` or just `dir /s /a h /a s` without an argument?  The former (which is what I've been doing) works, the latter (which I just realized you guys may be doing) gives file not found.

Comment: @Nicole: A-ha, now I've got what exactly you're doing wrong! 1) Please check that you don't have dirs named **s** and **h**. 2) Type `dir /s /a h /a s DirName` just like you mentioned. 3) Check the output *very carefully*. The 1st line should be "Volume in drive X is Y", the 2nd line "Volume Serial Number is Z", and most importantly, the 3rd line will be "File Not Found", while the 4th line of text will be "Directory of Drive:\Path\to\DirName" followed by the listing for DirName. That 3rd line is *extremely* important, please check if it's there.

Comment: Good catch, Karan.  I do indeed get the File Not Found message.  I missed it as it scrolled off the screen.  I'll correct my own answer to match yours and give you an up-vote. I had been focused on making sure the count was right on a big directory (comparing it to the result I knew was correct from `ls`.)

Comment: P.S. Karan, contact me offline, please.  I have something for you.

Comment: @Nicole: I've used the details on the Contact form of your site, hope the message gets through.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to count size of files on multiple network shares, symlinked as dirs in one root dir. "du" choked on that, giving me negative sizes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows Vista or later, it will come with PowerShell. You can then run this command directly from the command line:

```
powershell -c "Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'path_to_dir' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum"
```

`Sum` will be the size in bytes.

You can download and install PowerShell for some earlier versions of Windows. Additionally, I strongly recommend switching to PowerShell or a POSIX shell. The Windows command line (`cmd.exe`) is only good for more basic operations; beyond that it can get horrifyingly complex. Especially if you want one-liners.

Comment: And this is why Microsoft will never be able to kill off Linux.  `du -sh /path`.  You, too, can have simplified commands if you follow Bob's advice by installing a POSIX shell like CYGWIN.

Answer (score 1):

A great reference for dos/nt commands is http://ss64.com/; sometimes technet is better, but ss64 will also, at the bottom, list other related methods to accomplish similar deeds. ie: commands for particular results "DIRUSE" and sometimes even an equal Powershell command.

BTW - the gnuwin32 project has many of the core command utilities available from the nix world and usually there is one directly aimed at doing what needs doing... in this case the `du` command, where `du -b` will list the output size the same as `dir /A /S` and `du -h` makes it human readable. :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a "du" executable you can download.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du

Extract the executable in your Windows directory then for example this will list the size of all user's directories:

```
C:\Users>du64 -l 1 *
```